# Modifying the values of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

have an array like this
`"2021-1-1-1", "2019-1-2-1", "2020-1-1-1", "2020-1-2-1"`, - just need to keep the same format with `1st value - 3rd value?` how to? - any idea

trying something like this
`const modifiedArr = originalArr.map(name => ${name}man`);

but exactly how - not sure

Comment: Are you trying to remove an element from the array and eliminate the gap or are you trying to change the value of the  2nd element in the array?

Comment: I don't see how `${name}man` would perform `1st value - 3rd value` ?

Comment: i just tried that way, i know it will not do the stuff what i am doing,

Comment: I want to keep the First Value and the 3rd value like `2019-2, 2021-1`

Comment: oh wow, so `1st value - 3rd value` actually means `I want to keep the First Value and the 3rd value like 2019-2, 2021-1`? That's not what I understood _at all_ :)

Comment: Could you update your question, adding more information about what you are trying to achieve? Maybe put some output examples of what you want to be the final result in actual code syntax. This will help others find the solution for you.

Comment: @urn In order for us to help out better, update the question with the actually `array` data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to iterate over an array and do something to each value. As such you probably want to do something like this

```
new_arr = []
old_arr.forEach((ele)=>{
  ele_arr = ele.split("-") #break the dates into an array 
  modified_ele = ele_arr[0] + "-" + ele_arr[2] # grab the first and third elements
  new_arr.push(modified_ele)
})
```

(This can be better done with map, but we leave that as an exercise to the reader)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to simply keep upto the nth element, just

```
let arr = ["2021-1-1-1", "2019-1-2-1", "2020-1-1-1", "2020-1-2-1"]

let newArr = arr.map(item => item.slice(0, 7))
```

result: ["2021-1-1", "2019-1-2", "2020-1-1", "2020-1-2"]

or the answer your'e looking for,

```
let newArr = arr.map(item => { 
 let temp = item.split('-')
 return `${temp[0]}-${temp[2]}`
})
```

result: ["2021-1", "2019-2", "2020-1", "2020-2"]